# How to use adminer without password basing on login-password-less plugins

Tags: php, adminer

I want to use adminer without password.

I uploaded adminer-4.7.7-en.php file and finding login-password-less plugin
I create file plugins/login-password-less.php with content :

```
<?php

/** Enable login for password-less database
* @link https://www.adminer.org/plugins/#use
* @author Jakub Vrana, https://www.vrana.cz/
* @license https://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0 Apache License, Version 2.0
* @license https://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-2.0.html GNU General Public License, version 2 (one or other)
*/
class AdminerLoginPasswordLess {
    /** @access protected */
    var $password_hash;
    
    /** Set allowed password
    * @param string result of password_hash
    */
    function __construct($password_hash) {
        $this->password_hash = $password_hash;
    }

    function credentials() {
        $password = get_password();
        return array(SERVER, $_GET["username"], (password_verify($password, $this->password_hash) ? "" : $password));
    }
    
    function login($login, $password) {
        if ($password != "") {
            return true;
        }
    }

}
```

and reading https://www.adminer.org/plugins/#use I created file adminer.php, which is
located in one dir with adminer-4.7.7-en.php and I created new apache host pointed at this file.

This file has :

```
<?php
function adminer_object() {
    // required to run any plugin
    include_once "./plugins/login-password-less.php"; // Plugin I want to use

    // autoloader
    foreach (glob("plugins/*.php") as $filename) {
        include_once "./$filename";
    }

    $plugins = array(
        // specify enabled plugins here
        new AdminerLoginPasswordLess, // Plugin I want to use
/*        new AdminerTinymce,
        new AdminerFileUpload("data/"),
        new AdminerSlugify,
        new AdminerTranslation,
        new AdminerForeignSystem,*/
    );

    /* It is possible to combine customization and plugins:
    class AdminerCustomization extends AdminerPlugin {
    }
    return new AdminerCustomization($plugins);
    */

    return new AdminerPlugin($plugins); // I am not sure which class is it and where it is defined ?
}

// include original Adminer or Adminer Editor
include "./adminer-4.7.7-en.php";  // encoded file I uploaded
?>
```

and I got error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to function AdminerLoginPasswordLess::__construct(), 0 passed in /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/local_adminer/adminer.php on line 13 and exactly 1 expected in /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/local_adminer/plugins/login-password-less.php:16 Stack trace: #0 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/local_adminer/adminer.php(13): AdminerLoginPasswordLess->__construct() #1 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/local_adminer/adminer-4.7.7-en.php(1654): adminer_object() #2 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/local_adminer/adminer.php(31): include('/mnt/_work_sdb8...') #3 {main} thrown in /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/local_adminer/plugins/login-password-less.php on line 16
```

Which is the valid way  to use adminer without password ?

**MODIFIED:**
I made :

```
new AdminerLoginPasswordLess(hash("md5", 'my_sql_user_password')),
```

Is the selected "md5" method valid ?

But I got error :

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'AdminerPlugin' not found in /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/local_adminer/adminer.php:32 Stack trace: #0 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/local_adminer/adminer-4.7.7-en.php(1654): adminer_object() #1 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/local_adminer/adminer.php(36): include('/mnt/_work_sdb8...') #2 {main} thrown in /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/local_adminer/adminer.php on line 32
```

**MODIFIED:**
In source version of the site I foun file plugin.php with AdminerPlugin class implementation.
I moved this file under plugins directory.
In plugins/login-password-less.php I added reference to plugins/plugin.php file and added debugging info :

```
<?php

/** Enable login for password-less database
* @link https://www.adminer.org/plugins/#use
* @author Jakub Vrana, https://www.vrana.cz/
* @license https://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0 Apache License, Version 2.0
* @license https://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-2.0.html GNU General Public License, version 2 (one or other)
*/

include_once "./plugins/plugin.php";

class AdminerLoginPasswordLess {
    /** @access protected */
    var $password_hash;

    /** Set allowed password
    * @param string result of password_hash
    */
    function __construct($password_hash) {
        $this->password_hash = $password_hash;
        debToFile('-2 AdminerLoginPasswordLess->__construct:$this->password_hash::'.$this->password_hash);
        // That is debugging method appending  string into text file
    }

    function credentials() {
        $password = get_password();
        debToFile('-3 AdminerLoginPasswordLess->credentials:$password::'.$password);
        // That is debugging method appending  string into text file
        return array(SERVER, $_GET["username"], (password_verify($password, $this->password_hash) ? "" : $password));
    }

    function login($login, $password) {
        debToFile('-4 AdminerLoginPasswordLess->login:$login::'.$login);
        if ($password != "") {
            debToFile('-5 TRUE AdminerLoginPasswordLess->login:$login::'.$login);
        // That is debugging method appending  string into text file
            return true;
        }
        debToFile('-5 false AdminerLoginPasswordLess->login:$login::'.$login);
    }

}
```

and in adminer.php I added debugging line:

```
$plugins = array(
    new AdminerLoginPasswordLess(hash("md5", 'm8y2s8q&L')),

);
debToFile('-1After:AdminerLoginPasswordLess');
```

I loggin file I see:

```
<pre>::-2 AdminerLoginPasswordLess->__construct:$this->password_hash::c61d49aaab35ca428e60d764ff05159d</pre>
<pre>::-1After:AdminerLoginPasswordLess</pre>
```

It means that methods credentials and login of AdminerLoginPasswordLess class are not triggered.
I run in browser as :
http://local-adminer.com/?username=mysql_login_user

or
http://local-adminer.com  // host in apache config

and I have no errors, but I still have to enter password for mysql_login_user.

Did I miss some options/plugins?

Thanks!

Comment: Pls, look at MODIFIED block

Comment: It would help if you can upload the files to a repository. As you can see here [*plugins/#use*](https://www.adminer.org/en/plugins/#use), the `./plugins/plugin.php` is included before any plugin and you have changed that with including your plugin file which you don't have to do that way because your plugin will be loaded below into the autoloader  `foreach` loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first do

```sh
mkdir -p plugins;
wget -O plugins/plugin.php https://raw.githubusercontent.com/vrana/adminer/master/plugins/plugin.php;
nano plugins/passwordless_login.php
```

then write

```php
<?php
class AdminerLoginPasswordLess {
    public function credentials() {
        return array("mysql_hostname", "mysql_username", "mysql_password");
    }
    function login($login, $password) {
            return true;
    }
}
```

then save and exit, then run `nano adminer_with_plugins.php` and write:

```php
<?php
function adminer_object() {
    // required to run any plugin
    include_once "./plugins/plugin.php";
    
    // "autoloader"
    foreach (glob("plugins/*.php") as $filename) {
        include_once "./$filename";
    }
    
    $plugins = array(
        // specify enabled plugins here
        new AdminerLoginPasswordLess,
        //new AdminerDumpXml,
        //new AdminerTinymce,
        //new AdminerFileUpload("data/"),
        //new AdminerSlugify,
        //new AdminerTranslation,
        //new AdminerForeignSystem,
    );
    return new AdminerPlugin($plugins);
}

// include original Adminer or Adminer Editor
include "./adminer.php";
```

then save & exit;
then point your web-browser to `adminer_with_plugins.php` instead of `adminer.php`, now you have effectively disabled adminer's ability to login with different usernames/passwords/hosts, no matter what credentials you try to login with, it will always login with the mysql_hostname/mysql_username/mysql_password written in the source code, ignoring the user input credentials.

needless to say, this is quite a security-sensitive operation.

Comment: Thanks!, looks like that helped. I have login page and I can submit it without credentials. Has adminer session time parameter/tools? I would like to keep the current session as far as possible(including current db and table open), even after  browse closed/opened next day...

Comment: @mstdmstd i think Adminer has something like that, but PHP also has it, and web servers (nginx, apache, lighthttpd, etc) has it, and even web browers has it.. anyway, that belongs in a different thread ^^

Answer (score 1):

It often saves time if you can bypass small time consuming tasks. I tried above methods but did not work for me so I did the following which works in 2021 for Adminer 4.7.9.
**WARNING:** Please note that its only for your local machine & not advised for online databases.:
Step-1: Download Adminer source from Github, this [link](https://github.com/vrana/adminer).
Step-2: Open `adminer-master\adminer\include\auth.inc.php`
Step-3: Edit the following at lines 55 to 57 & replace my_username & my_password with your MySQL credentials:

```
$server = "localhost";  //$auth["server"];
$username = "my_username";    //$auth["username"];
$password = "my_password"; //(string) $auth["password"];
```

Step-4: Save & now open Adminer by pointing your browser to "adminer-master\adminer"
Step-5: Just click Login button & you will login without entering anything.
Hope it will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Years later I wanted to something similar again, but this time I needed to support multiple databases ("dev db" and "stage db" and "prod db"). Seems Adminer doesn't support it for more than 1 db, so this time i ended up with a little hack instead: make index.php

```
if (!empty($_GET['loadCredentialsInjector'])) {
    header("Content-Type: text/javascript");
?>
    function togglePredefinedCreds(profile) {
    let $$ = document.querySelectorAll.bind(document);
    let creds = {};
    if (profile === "stage") {
    creds.host = "stage-db.com";
    creds.dbuser = 'stage-username';
    creds.dbpass = 'stage-password';
    creds.dbname = "stage-dbname";
    }
    else if(profile === "prod") {
    creds.host = "prod-db.com";
    creds.dbuser = 'prod-username';
    creds.dbpass = 'prod-password';
    creds.dbname = "prod-dbname";
    }
    $$("input[name='auth[server]']")[0].value = creds.host;
    $$("input[name='auth[username]']")[0].value = creds.dbuser;
    $$("input[name='auth[password]']")[0].value = creds.dbpass;
    $$("input[name='auth[db]']")[0].value = creds.dbname;
    }
    {
    let loadStageButtonReference = loadStageButton;
    let loadProdButtonReference = loadProdButton;
    loadStageButton.parentNode.removeChild(loadStageButton);
    loadProdButton.parentNode.removeChild(loadProdButton);
    document.body.insertBefore(loadStageButtonReference, document.body.firstChild);
    document.body.insertBefore(document.createTextNode("   "), document.body.firstChild);
    document.body.insertBefore(loadProdButtonReference, document.body.firstChild);
    loadStageButtonReference.addEventListener("click", function () {togglePredefinedCreds("stage");});
    loadProdButtonReference.addEventListener("click", function () {togglePredefinedCreds("prod");});
    }
    <?php
    die();
}
if (empty($_POST) &&  in_array($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], array("/adminer/", "/adminer", "/adminer/index.php"), true)) {
    register_shutdown_function(function () {
        $nonce = explode("nonce-", print_r(headers_list(), true))[1];
        $nonce = substr($nonce, 0, strpos($nonce, "'"));
    ?>
        <button id="loadStageButton">load Stage</button>
        <button id="loadProdButton">load Prod</button>
        <script src="?loadCredentialsInjector=1" type="text/javascript" nonce="<?php echo $nonce; ?>"></script>
<?php
    });
}
require("adminer.php");
```

then in the top-left corner you get buttons to load your desired database on the log-in screen :)